# Error in passing the variable to url as a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the session variable to url in a variable 'var' am new to this please help me resolve the issue in below code line no 7.

**php**

```
           if($user){
                 $response["error"] = false;
                 $_SESSION['vault_no'] = $user['vault_no'];

                $to=$email;
                $subject = "Reset profile password";
                $txt = "Click on link to reset your profile password-> www.miisky.com/appmiisky/reset_pro.php?var = $_SESSION['vault_no']" ;
                $headers =  'From: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" ;
                $headers .= "BCC: prajwalkm7@gmail.com\r\n";
                $headers .=  'Reply-To: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
                /*$headers = 'From: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
                            'Cc: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();*/

                mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
                 echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

Comment: `reset_pro.php?var=" . $_SESSION['vault_no'] ;`

Comment: What *error* are you getting?

Comment: Can you show how does your output (email) is actually looking?

Comment: Thanks every one for responding..! Issue is resolved

Comment: rajdeep paul sir..!! sorry i missed to mention that.! Error was -> "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number"

Comment: sir why this variable is not visible in mail body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the text within double quote (") is taken as string

```
$txt = "Click on link to reset your profile password-> www.miisky.com/appmiisky/reset_pro.php?var = $_SESSION['vault_no']" ;
```

You need to contact your session value with string to get url

```
$txt = "Click on link to reset your profile password-> www.miisky.com/appmiisky/reset_pro.php?var=" . $_SESSION['vault_no'];
```